# "Few" after possessive adjectives: "He sold his few books"

Tags: meaning, word-difference, quantifiers, possessive-adjectives

When you say:

> He sold his **few** books.

Does it mean he sold a **few** books or he sold **few** books?

If it means **few** books, should I say:

> He sold his some books.

to mean he actually had some books?

Comment: It means he owned only a few books—and he sold those. (Both *a few* and *few* have the same meaning in this particular sentence: a small number of books. The phrase *his some books* is ungrammatical.

Comment: "His few [things]" is often seen.

Comment: Thank you for your kind explanations!

Comment: He sold a few of his books.
He sold some of his books.
He sold the few books he had.

He sold many of his books.
He sold (all) his numerous books.

Answer (score 1):

This means that he sold all of his books, and his books were few. In other words, he only had a few books to sell in the first place and he sold his books.

If we said either of these:

> He sold a few books.
>   He sold few books.

it means he sold a small number of books. It doesn't say how many books he had, only how many he sold.

I couldn't say why, but this construction is not used, even though it seems grammatically the same:

> He sold his some books.

You can, however, say this. It means he had many books and he sold them all.

> He sold his many books.